# copy row data from previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like below:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║                  Id                  ║ ContiguousSubnetStart ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║ 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 ║ 10.60.66.8            ║
║ 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 ║ 1                     ║
║ 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 ║ 10.60.66.18           ║
║ 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 ║ 1                     ║
║ 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 ║ 1                     ║
║ 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 ║ 1                     ║
║ 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 ║ 1                     ║
║ B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7 ║ 10.60.88.28           ║
║ B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7 ║ 1                     ║
║ B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7 ║ 1                     ║
║ B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7 ║ 1                     ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

I would like this table to transform into:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║                  Id                  ║ ContiguousSubnetStart ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║ 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 ║ 10.60.66.8            ║
║ 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 ║ 10.60.66.8            ║
║ 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 ║ 10.60.66.18           ║
║ 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 ║ 10.60.66.18           ║
║ 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 ║ 10.60.66.18           ║
║ 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 ║ 10.60.66.18           ║
║ 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 ║ 10.60.66.18           ║
║ B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7 ║ 10.60.88.28           ║
║ B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7 ║ 10.60.88.28           ║
║ B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7 ║ 10.60.88.28           ║
║ B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7 ║ 10.60.88.28           ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

without using cursors. `ip-address`  followed by 1's represent one group.

Comment: Do you have any unique column like ID/creation_date?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? It matters, because recent versions make stuff like this pretty easy.

Comment: How are the rows sorted? There seems to be no column or data upon which you can sort to guarantee the order you show in your first sample, which makes obtaining the second sample nearly impossible.

Comment: lad2025, yes I have unique Id which is a guid

Comment: sql server 2012 on azure

Comment: @pmbAustin order by id, ContiguousSubnetStart

Comment: can you give Name and data type of the unique column? Also, Is there a creation_date column?

Comment: @ManthanPatel the unique column is of type uniqueidentifier and its name unId

Comment: Would you need the result to be read-only?

Comment: Not that is not the output from order by id, ContiguousSubnetStart.   Really  1 sorts before and after 10.60.66.18?  You cannot copy from previous until "previous" is defined.

Comment: Just curious: why "without cursors"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such manipulations need some column on which you can order rows in order to get desired result. In the example I have manually added such a column `rn` using window function `row_number`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ,
      ContiguousSubnetStart VARCHAR(100)
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1', '10.60.66.8' ),
        ( '53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1', '1' ),
        ( '53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1', '10.60.66.18' ),
        ( '53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1', '1' ),
        ( '53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1', '1' ),
        ( '53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1', '1' ),
        ( '53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1', '1' ),
        ( 'B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7', '10.60.88.28' ),
        ( 'B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7', '1' ),
        ( 'B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7', '1' ),
        ( 'B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7', '1' )


;WITH cte AS(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) rn FROM @t)
SELECT oa.Id, oa.ContiguousSubnetStart 
FROM cte t1
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 * 
            FROM cte t2 
            WHERE t1.Id = t2.Id AND t2.ContiguousSubnetStart <> '1' AND t2.rn <= t1.rn 
            ORDER BY rn DESC)oa
```

If you select from `cte` you will see:

```
Id                                      ContiguousSubnetStart   rn
53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1    10.60.66.8              1
53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1    1                       2
53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1    10.60.66.18             3
53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1    1                       4
53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1    1                       5
53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1    1                       6
53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1    1                       7
B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7    10.60.88.28             8
B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7    1                       9
B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7    1                       10
B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7    1                       11
```

If you have such a column like incrementing identity or date column using which you can unambigiously order the data in your table just use that column instead of `rn` and you won't need cte any more. Say that column name is `SomeOrderingColumn`, then your statement will look like:

```
SELECT oa.Id, oa.ContiguousSubnetStart 
FROM TableName t1
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 * 
            FROM TableName t2 
            WHERE t1.Id = t2.Id AND t2.ContiguousSubnetStart <> '1' 
                  AND t2.SomeOrderingColumn <= t1.SomeOrderingColumn
            ORDER BY SomeOrderingColumn DESC)oa
```

Without that ordering column you may still get the desired result, but that will not be guarantied under all circumstances and you can encounter some day that you are getting wrong results. This was discussed many times and you can find out that you are guarantied to get ordered results only and only if you explicitly use `ORDER BY` clause. But you can not order your data with `guid` or `ip` columns. So you will have to add one more column to your table that will guaranty ordering like incrementing `ID` or `DateTime` column.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a WHILE loop with a row count, not sure which would be better performance wise for your environment.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
  Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ,
  ContiguousSubnetStart VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT  INTO #Test
VALUES  ( '53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1', '10.60.66.8' ),
    ( '53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1', '1' ),
    ( '53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1', '10.60.66.18' ),
    ( '53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1', '1' ),
    ( '53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1', '1' ),
    ( '53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1', '1' ),
    ( '53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1', '1' ),
    ( 'B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7', '10.60.88.28' ),
    ( 'B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7', '1' ),
    ( 'B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7', '1' ),
    ( 'B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7', '1' )

SELECT *, [RN] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) INTO #NewTable FROM #Test

DECLARE @Count INT = (SELECT MAX(RN) FROM #NewTable)
DECLARE @CurrentRow INT = 1

WHILE @Count > 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE #NewTable
    SET ContiguousSubnetStart = (SELECT ContiguousSubnetStart FROM #NewTable WHERE RN = @CurrentRow - 1)
    WHERE ContiguousSubnetStart = '1'
    AND RN = @CurrentRow

    SET @CurrentRow = @CurrentRow + 1
    SET @Count = @Count - 1
END
```

Result Set:

```
===========================================================
| 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 | 10.60.66.8  | 1  |
| 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 | 10.60.66.8  | 2  |
| 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 | 10.60.66.18 | 3  |
| 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 | 10.60.66.18 | 4  |
| 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 | 10.60.66.18 | 5  |
| 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 | 10.60.66.18 | 6  |
| 53DC370E-8C7D-4526-9292-35125443E4B1 | 10.60.66.18 | 7  |
| B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7 | 10.60.88.28 | 8  |
| B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7 | 10.60.88.28 | 9  |
| B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7 | 10.60.88.28 | 10 |
| B6F8484C-B8F9-4CB0-B6BF-395A7599FFB7 | 10.60.88.28 | 11 |
===========================================================
```

Comment: First of all you missed the most important part of the statement... 
Secondly, I can't see how looping on @count can be helpful. When to update @Count? How to update IP?

Comment: More information added. You could have just asked me for more information rather than down vote me because you don't understand. This is a tested answer.

Comment: Nothing personal. We are here to make site better. Downvote is just a signal for author to make his post better. As soon as it is good and works downvoters will just undownvote. Happy coding!

Comment: Ok, thanks for un down voting, I retract my objection.